# Make PHP variable accessible throughout webpage

Tags: php, url, variables, opencart

I using opencart, passing a product name to the contact page, to be used in the querybox.

URL passed in:
http://www.webpage.com/index.php?route=information/contact&id=product_name

Within `<head>` tags: `<?php $productid = $_GET['id']?>`

`$productid` can be accessed within the head, but is undefined elsewhere on the page where needed.

How can I access this variable in the body?

Comment: As long as the rest of the page is executing in the same scope, it should be available. You may need to access it as `$GLOBALS['productid']`, but also `$_GET` should be available everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using it like that in the first place. OpenCart has built in variables for request vars. Use `$this->request->get['id']` instead